# How to Keep the parent menu highlighted when I click on its child menu

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I am using the following jquery

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#menu-wplook-main-menu').find('li a').click(function () {
      $('#menu-wplook-main-menu').find('li a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
      $($(this)
        .closest('li.menu-item')
        .children()[0]).addClass('active');
    });
  });
</script>
```

My css

```
<style>
  #menu-wplook-main-menu li a.active {
    color:#e53b51;
    background: blue;
  }
</style>
```

My html

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="menu-wplook-main-menu" >
  <li role="presentation"> 
    <a class="dropdown-toggle has-submenu cursor_pointer" href="index.php"> Home </a>                                     
  </li>
  <li role="presentation menuli menulixl root" class="menu-item">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle has-submenu cursor_pointer cursor_pointer" href=""> Services <span class="sub-arrow"></span> </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu multimenu multimenuxl vbghno sm-nowrap" style="min-width: 10em; max-width: 40em; top: auto; left: 0px; margin-left: -117px; width: auto; margin-top: -1px;">
      <li class="col-xs-12">
        <!--<a class="splhed" href="">Software Development</a>-->
        <a class="levelmenu" href="trav_port.php">Travel Portal Development</a>
        <a class="levelmenu" href="GDS_integ.php">GDS Integrations</a>
        <a class="levelmenu" href="xml_api_integ.php">XML/API Integrations</a>
        <a class="levelmenu" href="white_label_web.php">White Label Website</a>
        <a class="levelmenu" href="Hotel_Cab_portal.php">Hotel & Cab Portal Development</a>  
        <a class="levelmenu" href="travel_web.php">Travel Website Designing</a>   
        <a class="levelmenu" href="mobile_app_dev.php">Mobile Apps Development</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation" class="menu-item">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle has-submenu cursor_pointer" href=""> Products <span class="sub-arrow cursor_pointer"></span> </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu multimenu multimenuxl vbghno sm-nowrap" style="min-width: 10em; max-width: 40em; top: auto; left: 0px; margin-left: -117px; width: auto; margin-top: -1px;">
      <li class="col-xs-12"> 
        <a class="levelmenu" href="trav_portal.php">Travel Portal</a>
        <a class="levelmenu" href="travsoft.php">Travsoft</a>
        <a class="levelmenu" href="white_label.php">White label</a>
        <a class="levelmenu" href="hotel_extranet.php">Hotel Extranet</a> 
        <a class="levelmenu" href="holiday_manage.php">Holiday Management System</a>  
        <a class="levelmenu" href="hotrl_crs.php">Hotel CRS</a> 
      </li>
    </ul>               
  </li>               
</ul>
```

If I do not use the PHP link in href it works perfectly. But if I use the PHP link in href it is not working.

**Question**

Should I change anything in my PHP file?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working fine. Your jQuery could be a bit cleaned up. For example:

```
$('#menu-wplook-main-menu li a').click(function () {
    $('#menu-wplook-main-menu .active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).closest('li.menu-item').children().first().addClass('active');
});
```

But I think you main problem is that when clicking your links you navigate to a new page. So you reload the whole menu, and have no state of it left. and start from scratch.

You would need a function perhaps that will take your page from current address, look for the menu item and highlight it.

If you replace all your .php links with #1, #2 etc it works fine.

So either a load function, or load stuff with ajax maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".dropdown-menu a").on("click",function(){

        $(".dropdown-toggle").removeClass("active");

            $(this).closest(".menu-item").find(".dropdown-toggle").addClass("active");

    })
})
```

Final code :

i change `href` to # for test :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <style>
        .active {
             color:#e53b51;
             background: blue;
         }
    </style>
My html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="menu-wplook-main-menu" >
                            <li role="presentation"> 
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle has-submenu cursor_pointer" href="index.php"> Home </a>                                     
                            </li>
    
                            <li role="presentation menuli menulixl root" class="menu-item">
                                
                                <a class="dropdown-toggle has-submenu cursor_pointer cursor_pointer" href=""> Services
                                    <span class="sub-arrow"></span> 
                                </a>
                                
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu multimenu multimenuxl vbghno sm-nowrap" style="min-width: 10em; max-width: 40em; top: auto; left: 0px; margin-left: -117px; width: auto; margin-top: -1px;">
                                    <li class="col-xs-12">
                                        <!--<a class="splhed" href="">Software Development</a>-->
                                        <a class="levelmenu" href="#">Travel Portal Development</a>
                                        <a class="levelmenu" href="#">GDS Integrations</a>
                                        <a class="levelmenu" href="#">XML/API Integrations</a>
                                        <a class="levelmenu" href="#">White Label Website</a>
                                        <a class="levelmenu" href="#">Hotel & Cab Portal Development</a>  
                                        <a class="levelmenu" href="#">Travel Website Designing</a>   
                                        <a class="levelmenu" href="#">Mobile Apps Development</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                
                            </li>
    
                            <li role="presentation" class="menu-item">                                 
                                <a class="dropdown-toggle has-submenu cursor_pointer" href=""> Products <span class="sub-arrow cursor_pointer"></span> </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu multimenu multimenuxl vbghno sm-nowrap" style="min-width: 10em; max-width: 40em; top: auto; left: 0px; margin-left: -117px; width: auto; margin-top: -1px;">
                                    <li class="col-xs-12"> 
                                        <a class="levelmenu" href="#">Travel Portal</a>
                                        <a class="levelmenu" href="#">Travsoft</a>
                                        <a class="levelmenu" href="#">White label</a>
                                        <a class="levelmenu" href="#">Hotel Extranet</a> 
                                        <a class="levelmenu" href="#">Holiday Management System</a>  
                                        <a class="levelmenu" href="#">Hotel CRS</a> 
                                    </li>
                                </ul>               
                            </li>                               
                        </ul>
        
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $(".dropdown-menu a").on("click",function(){

                $(".dropdown-toggle").removeClass("active");

                    $(this).closest(".menu-item").find(".dropdown-toggle").addClass("active");

            })
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```